# What is the appropriateFor parameter for in FileManager.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)?

Tags: swift, temporary-directory

[Apple's instructions for creating a temporary URL](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url) are to use `FileManager.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`.
The example they give is (rewritten in Swift 3):

```
let desktopURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Noah/Desktop/")
do {
    let temporaryDirectoryURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .itemReplacementDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: desktopURL, create: true)
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

The docs say that the `appropriateFor` parameter "determines the volume of the returned URL", but I don't understand what that means. What is this parameter for and how should I determine the URL to pass in for it?

Comment: Are you using Swift 2 or 3? Your code appears to be Swift 2 but your are quoting Swift 3 documentation and class names.

Comment: I'm using Swift 3. The official documentation I linked is written in Swift 2, but that doesn't really make a difference to the question.

Comment: You have it backwards. In Swift 3 you should use `URL`, not `NSURL` and `FileManager`, not `NSFileManager`. It will be easier to answer your Swift 3 question if you post actual Swift 3 code using the updated APIs.

Comment: The url doesn't matter as long as it points to a fileURL in the volume where you want the temporary url to be located

Comment: Thank you. And for the record, the reason why my code was in Swift 2 before was because I was quoting the documentation that I linked. Sorry if I hadn't made that clear.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's the global temp directory. This function creates a new subdirectory within it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL that you pass in is used to determine on which Volume (on which mounted disk) the temporary directory will be created.  I suspect you should pass a URL to a file or folder that would reside on the same volume.

Comment: You might just want to use `FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

I Did an experiment to understand it.

```
let document = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
try? FileManager.default.url(for: .itemReplacementDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: document, create: true)
```

A directory appears in sandbox of my app:
[image]
So I think `appropriateFor` is used to determine where a temporary directory will be created

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today, years later, but the docs have are clear on this now. I don't remember that they were before, but here's your answer direct from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url):

> The file URL used to determine the location of the returned URL.
>
> Only the volume of this parameter is used. This parameter is ignored
> unless the directory parameter contains the value
> FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.itemReplacementDirectory and the
> domain parameter contains the value userDomainMask.